# Latest PayPal Upgrade Notification

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment

Recently, our client got an email from PayPal regarding their service upgrade. I know about the SSL upgrade which took place around December 2014 due to `poodle attack`

I am unaware about this new upgrade, also i don't know if it will affect the payments on Magento website.

I read the documentation for [System Upgrade](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/487047/1429640303/redirect/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDMxNjExNzA3L3NpZC9Zbk9mR2ptbQ==/filename/2015%20Merchant%20Security%20System%20Upgrade%20Guide%20(U.K.%20English).pdf) provided by them. It suggests changes in the API and other stuffs. But i am not sure if these changes will affect Magento - PayPal integration.

If yes, will there be any upgrade patch released? I am sure, till now there is no upgrade patch released.

The mail my client received is as below:

> PayPal service upgrades for merchants: You may need to take action.
>
> We're contacting our merchants with some important information in
>   response to an industry-wide security upgrade, not unique to PayPal.
>   This change involves upgrading Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificates
>   over the course of 2015 and 2016.
>
> Since these changes are technical in nature, we advise you to consult
>   your partner, website provider, or the people responsible for your
>   PayPal integration. They will be able to identify if any changes will
>   be needed. If you don't have a technology team, you should change
>   this, and we can work with them to ensure that you continue to process
>   payments through your current integration with PayPal. Full technical
>   details can be found in our Merchant Security System Upgrade Guide. In
>   addition, our 2015-2016 SSL Certificate Change microsite contains a
>   schedule of our service upgrade plan.
>
> If you have any questions, please contact our Merchant Technical
>   Support team for technical support.
>
> Thanks for your patience as we continue to improve our services.

It would be of great help, if someone can provide an insight on it.

**EIDT**

> Our client got another email regarding it. The mail content is as
>   below:
>
> As we have previously communicated to you, PayPal is upgrading the
>   certificate for www.paypal.com to SHA-256. This endpoint is also used
>   by merchants using the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) product.
>
> This upgrade is scheduled for 30/9/2015; however, we may need to
>   change this date on short notice to you to align to the industry
>   security standard.
>
> You’re receiving this notification because you’ve been identified as a
>   merchant who has used IPN endpoints within the past year. If you have
>   not made the necessary changes, we urge you to do so right away to
>   avoid a disruption of your service!
>
> Because these changes are technical in nature, we advise that you
>   consult with your individuals responsible for your PayPal integration.
>   They will be able to identify what, if any, changes are needed. Please
>   share this email and the hyperlinks below with your technical contact
>   for evaluation.
>
> Testing in the Sandbox is one of the best ways to make sure your
>   integrations work. Sandbox endpoints have been upgraded to accept
>   secure connections by the SHA-256 Certificates.
>
> Full technical details can be found in our Merchant Security System
>   Upgrade Guide. In addition, our 2015-2016 SSL Certificate Change
>   microsite contains a schedule of our service upgrade plan.
>
> Thanks for your patience as we continue to improve our services.

I am really confused if this in any way effect the integration of PayPal Standard or Express checkout with Magento. I am not a server expert to figure it out.

Can anyone please provide an insight on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this too. You're probably looking at this blog article, right? https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/

The translation is that they're going to use SSL certificates which have stronger encryption on them. All you need to do is make sure your server supports it. Which means - ask your hosting provider.

You actually shouldn't have to do anything in Magento itself. This is all server-level material. Magento itself doesn't actually do the encryption/decryption, it makes a call to the server which handles that.

To be 100% certain, call your hosting provider about this. Tell them that you got this email about paypal upgrading their SSL certs to SHA-256, and you want to make sure your server supports it.

Most likely, they'll tell you they upgraded months ago.

Comment: does that mean a Magento site will need SSL certificate from Sep 30th?

Comment: Nope. From our perspective, everything's the same as it was before. It's just that when your server communicates to paypal for a purchase, that connection between the two systems will be using a stronger encryption.

(That said, getting an SSL is generally a pretty good idea.)